# using httplib2 Python to create REST POST listener

Tags: python-2.7, rest, post, httplib2

I found woefully few samples of httplib2 using the following template defined in the httplib2 documents.

The following (GETs) work (and I now need to implement POST methods using it)

```
URLS = (
    '/',                 'PingLocal',
    '/ping',             'PingLocal',
    '/ping/silo',        'PingSilo'
)
class PingLocal(object):
    def GET(self):
        return json.dumps({'time': time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S'), 'message': 'XYZ Server Responding to Ping'})
```

How to implement POST methods and pass data (body) to the post request?
A few examples I did come across do not use this suggested

**"URLS-list / Classes"** model.

Any pointers appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake.
In the code I am implementing the REST Server AND in the implemented methods - I am in turn making REST client calls to remote URIs.

I am using httplib2 to make those REST client calls (as the library documentation clearly mentions - its the client library).

I am in turn using web.py module to implement the REST server - and found the relevant documentation there.

Thank you